# Conditional dictionary explicit initialization

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to add to the list a dictionary based on the number of elements in a given tuple. The idea is below:

```
# t is tuple containing 1 or 2 elements, l is list
l = list()
l.append({
    'A': t[0],
    if len(t) > 1: ('B': t[1])
})
```

So, if `t = [7, 8]` then `l = [{'A': 7, 'B': 8}]` and if `t = [7]` then `l = [{'A': 7}]`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The options are only one or two elements?

Comment: Please reconsider which answer you have accepted.  Jblasco's works, but ajcr's is much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the zip function stops in the shortest of the two emails, I like the option:

```
l.append({key:value for key, value in zip(['A', 'B'], t)})
```

Comment: `{key: value for key, value in ...}` is equivalent to `dict(...)`.

Comment: You can also `import string` and use `string.letters.upper()[:26]` in the palce of `['A', 'B']`. It makes it a little more extensible in case you don't know the length of `t`.

Comment: You are right, @ColinvH. That's the answer that ajcr posted a minute before I did, while I was writting mine. In all fairness, ajcr should be the chosen "right" answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an `if` statement.

```
d = { 'A':t[0] }
if len(t) > 1:
     d['B'] = t[1]
l = [d]
```

Or you could use a comprehension:

```
l = [ { chr(ord('A')+i):v for i,v in enumerate(t) } ]
```

That will work if the length of your tuple is between 0 and 26. (After that you run out of letters.)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could write the following line to create the dictionary:

```
[dict(zip(['A', 'B'], t))]
```

Then if `t = [7, 8]`:

```
>>> [dict(zip(['A', 'B'], t))]
[{'A': 7, 'B': 8}]
```

And if `t = [7]`:

```
>>> [dict(zip(['A', 'B'], t))]
[{'A': 7}]
```

The function `zip` creates tuples from `t` and the list of letters only up to the length of the shortest list. `dict` maps the tuples to dictionary keys/values.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional expression should be written like so:

```
l.append({'A': t[0], 'B': t[1]} if len(t) > 1 else {'A': t[0]})
```

If the tuple has more than one item, then we add `{'A': t[0], 'B': t[1]}` to the list.  Otherwise, we add `{'A': t[0]}`.

---

Alternately, you could add `dict(zip('AB', t))` to the list:

```
l.append(dict(zip('AB', t)))
```

this will work in either case:

```
>>> t = (1, 2)
>>> dict(zip('AB', t))
{'A': 1, 'B': 2}
>>> t = (1,)
>>> dict(zip('AB', t))
{'A': 1}
>>>
```